# What is the prerequisite when try to learn the spring or struts framework?

Tags: java, spring, struts2, prerequisites

I think these technologies are really prior to java industry

Comment: Just skip Struts and learn Struts2 or even better Spring MVC since you are going to learn Spring

Comment: The main prerequisite is having a brain ;)

Comment: I'd say a JEE brain, a JBrain!!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm not sure about struts, but for Spring, it helps to know about [dependency injection and inversion of control](http://martinfowler.com/articles/injection.html), [XML](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/default.asp), and [JavaBeans](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/javabeans/index.html).

If I had to recommend a book, it would be [Spring in Action](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1933988134)

#### UPDATE

It's been pointed out to me that Spring in Action is about Spring 2.0, which it is. Spring 2.0 is almost four years old. Spring's first-party documentation makes wonderful reading. Check out the [reference documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/) for great prose and the [Javadocs](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/) if you need more in-depth information.

Comment: Agreed. The Spring documentation, which you can get as a PDF, is very good and has a lot of examples. Pretend it's a book and read the whole thing.

Answer (score 11):

A good knowledge of Core Java, Servlets and JSP is pretty much more than enough you need..

Answer (score 3):

In my opinion, the Spring in Action book is a bit behind the times now (Spring 2.0) and doesn't include any of the nifty new features in 2.5 or 3.0.  I would start with the [spring documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/).

Answer (score 1):

Only in reference to Spring.
If your not familiar with [dependancy injection](http://martinfowler.com/articles/injection.html), then spend a bit of time reading. I'd also suggest that your java knowledge includes being comfortable with Annotations, Reflection and even [Aspect orientated programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming). Most Spring books fail to keep pace, so unless your forced to use a particular version Spring 3.0 should be your starting point as this has many additions which can save a lot of time.

Answer (score -2):

In reference to spring it is mandatory to have a little knowledge of J2SE, J2EE(Servlets, JDBC little bit), XML Schema and rest of the things you can learn while studying Spring Framework. Most of all JAVA knowledge is required :)